# TYPO3 TCA label with UserFunc - how to get HTML formatted label?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I want to format the title showing in a list of TCA items which can contain italic text. But whatever I try, I get only unformatted text - even from RTE text fields.

My base information is "partA", "partB", "partC" and I need a title like "partA : partC - part B"

My Code so far:

```
<?php
return [
    'ctrl' => [
        'title' => 'LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/myext.xlf:tx_myext_domain_model_myitem',
        'label' => 'partC',
        'label_alt' => 'partA',
        'formattedLabel_userFunc' => T395\myExt\Classes\UserFuncs\MyBEUserFuncs::class.'->getFullMyitemTitle',
        'formattedLabel_userFunc_options' => [
            'sys_file' => [
                'partC','partA','partB'
            ]
        ],
        'iconfile' => 'fileadmin/Resource/icons/svgs/myext.svg',
    ],
    'columns' => [
        'partC' => [
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/myext.xlf:tx_myext_domain_model_myitem.partC',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'text',
                'enableRichtext' => true,
            ],
        ],
        'partA' => [
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/myext.xlf:tx_myext_domain_model_myitem.partA',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => '5',
                'eval' => 'trim',
            ],
        ],
        'partB' => [
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/myext.xlf:tx_myext_domain_model_myitem.partC',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => '5',
                'eval' => 'trim',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'types' => [
        '0' => ['showitem' => 'partA,partB,partC'],
    ],
];
```

And the UF:

```
<?php

T395\myExt\Classes\UserFuncs;

class MyBEUserFuncs
{   
    public function getFullMyitemTitle(&$params, &$pObj)
    {
        echo "Hello World!";
        $params['title'] = $params['row']['partA'].' : '.$params['row']['partC'].' - '.$params['row']['partB'];
    }
}
```

Even the `echo` is not showing. Changing the `formattedLabel_userFunc` to `label_userFunc` results in getting a string in right order - but right without any text formats like `<i>` etc but showing them as text. I'm sure, I'm missing something, but I can't figure out what it is - I was also unable to find any code snippets or examples showing the right way - and the docs from TYPO3 saying only that exists `formattedLabel_userFunc` and it has options - but no proper example there. Hope you can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in the [documentation for formattedlabel_userfunc](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/9.5/en-us/Ctrl/Index.html#formattedlabel-userfunc) you can find:

> [...] return formatted HTML for the label and used **only for the labels of inline (IRRE) records**.

and for [label_userfunc](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/9.5/en-us/Ctrl/Index.html#label-userfunc) there is the warning:

> The title is passed later on through htmlspecialchars() so it may not include any HTML formatting.

Comment: Okay, that doesn't get me anywhere. That is about the same in the documentation, which just does not help me because there is no suitable example.

Comment: you will not find an example as it is not possible. that is stated clearly in the documents.

Comment: Okay, I found my issue by random now, while searching for another solution. There's a specific column type 'inline' which takes that formatted UF - unfortuneatly that's not stated in the description from formatted UF nor has it  a link to the inline column element to which it refers. Now the way of function is right clear. 
I misunderstood the term "inline" because I thought that generally refers to the title in conjunction with the CSS attribute "inline". The difference ist not really clear to somebody who isn't familiar with the TCA-Programming in that way, at the first moment.

Comment: A proper example at that point would do the trick to understand, that the formatted UF will only work with inline column items. Thank you for answering anyway :)

Comment: TYPO3 documentation is rebuild at the moment but mostly it still lacks examples. Everybody is able to support the documentation team with a pullrequest. just push the Button "Edit on github" at the top of each manual page.

Comment: You're right, but to do this I first needed to understand how it works ;)

Comment: It seems that the userfunc gets applied after the "label_alt" definition have been processed despite. So overriding the label in this way for the INLINE field bacause of performance issues doesn't result in better performance.